# Handle cell click state on React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have this state defined:

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            posts:[],
            post:{},
            openNew:false,
            openModify:false
        };
    }
```

With the following function which contains a fetch, I recieve an array of objects with responseData:

```
getPosts(){
        fetch(
            DOMAIN+'/api/posts/', {
                method: 'get',
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Authorization':'Bearer '+this.props.token
                }
            })
            .then((response) =>
            {
                return response.json();
            })
            .then((responseData) => {
                this.setState({posts:responseData});
                console.log("Log del responseData de posts");
                console.log(responseData);
            })
            .catch(function() {
                console.log("error");
            });
    }
```

This function is called in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount(){
        this.getPosts()
    }
```

The JSON object obtained from the fetch and kept within `this.state.products` looks like this:

[image: CAPTURE OF THE JSON OBJECT]

As shown previously in the fetch, with this line `this.setState({posts:responseData});` I can pass `posts` to the table where I want `title`, `date` and `hour` to be displayed:

```
<DataTables
    height={'auto'}
    selectable={false}
    showRowHover={true}
    columns={CAMPAIGN_TABLE_COLUMNS}
    data={this.state.posts}
    showCheckboxes={false}
    rowSizeLabel="Filas por página"
    onCellClick={this.handleOpenModify.bind(this)}
                />
```

The table called is:

```
const CAMPAIGN_TABLE_COLUMNS = [
    {
        key: 'title',
        label: 'Título',
        style:{width: '40%'}
    }, {
        key: 'created',
        label: 'Fecha',
        style:{width: '30%'},
        render: (DateToFormat) => {
            return moment(DateToFormat).format("DD/MM/YYYY");
        }
    }, {
        key: 'created',
        label: 'Hora',
        style:{width: '30%'},
        render: (DateToFormat) => {
            return moment(DateToFormat).format("hh:mm:ss");
        }
    }
];
```

With all of this I am able to print the data that I want on the table, looking like this:
[image]

What I am not able to do is: **When I click on a row of the table to pass the values that were previously printed, such as the title.**

[image]

This dialog is constructed using the following lines:

```
                 <Dialog
                    title="Modificar Post"
                    actions={actions}
                    modal={false}
                    open={this.state.openModify}
                    onRequestClose={this.handleClose}
                    titleClassName="dialog-title"
                    contentStyle={{width:660}}
                    autoScrollBodyContent={true}
                >
                    <TextField
                        fullWidth={true}
                        floatingLabelText="Título"
                        errorText="¡Ups! No deberías ver este mensaje."
                        defaultValue={this.state.posts.title}
                    />
                </Dialog>
```

I thought that binding `this` to `handleOpenModify` (the function that is called when you click on a row of the table):

```
handleOpenModify = () => {
        this.getPosts();
        this.setState({openModify: true});
    };
```

Would allow me to print the title within the `TextField` as simple as giving to the `defaultValue` `this.state.posts.title`, but is not working as you can see on the last picture that I added.

P.D.: I call `getPosts()` in `handleOpenModify` in case it had to be called again when a row is clicked, but it hasn't worked either.

Any suggestions?

Comment: it seems you're on the wrong direction of handling your data. i think what you're trying to do is just to retrieve the title of the clicked cell/row/item. remember that you still have the data stored from your last getPosts. why not retrieve the data of the respective cell on click? bind an onclick pass the id and retrieve the info from list

Comment: May i know are you setting `post: []` in the state on clicking row? or why are you using this in state. ?

Comment: @Semi-Friends Yes, that's what I want. I am a little bit saturated now. Could you write as an answer an approximation on how should I bind an onclick to pass the id and retrieve the data that I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: as @Semi-Friends mentioned you can do that easily. However I don't think that the `onCellClick` method of the third party **dataTable** plugin won't have any input parameters. I don't know exactly what plugin are you using but it should give you the current row or cell as a parameter.

Comment: @NarasimhaReddy If you are referring to `post{}`, is an unused parameter in the state.

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan dataTable is a plugin that comes from material-ui.com

Comment: @Eartair
`onCellClick function  Called when a row cell is clicked. rowNumber is the row number and columnId is the column number or the column key.`
judging from this line of documentation `onCellClick(rowNumber, columnId)` is the actual prot of the method so  your method can have two params first one will be your **row number** second one will be your **column Id** this should be enough to identify the post on which user clidked

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan Thanks to your explanation I've managed to find the solution. Thank you. I'll post my changes as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @EdwardChopuryan and @Semi-Friends I've been able to retrieve the data that I wanted.

First of all I had to change the name of my function `handleOpenModify` to `handleCellClick`, since I could pass through the `row` parameter all I wanted and keep it within `post {}`, declared before in the sate.

```
handleCellClick = (y,x,row) => {
        this.getPosts();
        this.setState({
            openModify: true,
            newForm:false,
            post:{...row, _id:row._id,title:row.title}})
    };
```

Then, on `DataTable`, bind it on the `onCellClick` parameter:

```
<DataTables
    height={'auto'}
    selectable={false}
    showRowHover={true}
    columns={CAMPAIGN_TABLE_COLUMNS}
    data={this.state.posts}
    showCheckboxes={false}
    rowSizeLabel="Filas por página"
    onCellClick={this.handleCellClick.bind(this)}
                />
```

And call the value that I wanted on the `TextField` through the `defaultValue`:

```
<TextField
      fullWidth={true}
      floatingLabelText="Título"
      errorText="¡Ups! No deberías ver este mensaje."
      defaultValue={this.state.post.title}
           />
```

And this is the result!

[image]

Comment: just a tip. If you use double arrow function you don't need to bind manually it will do that for you

Answer (score 0):

`DataTables` provides you the `rowNumber` and `columnIndex` as arguments.

For more information, check their docs: 
https://github.com/hyojin/material-ui-datatables/blob/master/src/DataTables/DataTablesRow.js#L142

```
<DataTables
  ...
  onCellClick={(event, rowNumber) => console.log('selectedPost', this.state.posts[rowNumber]) }
/>
```

Comment: DataTables is a plugin from material-ui.

Comment: @Eartair by looking at the docs, they return the `rowNumber` so you can use it with `posts` array. I've just updated the code sample :)

Comment: @HemersonCarlin the first parameter shouldn't be rowNumber? you pass it as an event it might be confusing

Comment: @EdwardChopuryan I thought so. However, if you look at the link I've posted they send 3 arguments: `event`, `rowNumber` and `columnIndex`.

Comment: Yep sorry. My bad :)

Answer (score 0):

this is a sample on how to bind and retrieve specific data on click of cell

list item creation

```
var list = CAMPAIGN_TABLE_COLUMNS.map((data, key) =>
    <td onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, key)}>{data.title}</td>
)
```

onClick handler

```
handleClick(id) {
    let item = CAMPAIGN_TABLE_COLUMNS[id]; // item data
}
```

as for your current code, you need to modify this part

```
onCellClick={this.handleOpenModify.bind(this)} // key or the array index

handleOpenModify(e, row, key) { // receive the column number as 3rd param
  let item = CAMPAIGN_TABLE_COLUMNS[key]; // now get the respective object
}
```

Comment: I believe `onCellClick` method has 2 params one is rowNumber the second one is column Id. this is not necessary ))

Comment: ow. i thought it was for his row creation. it seems like this is for the whole table creation. will modify the answer in a bit